# $(\ell^{1})^{*}$ isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^{\infty}$ as a corollary of Riesz representation Theorem.

Tags: isometry, vector-space-isomorphism, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm following "A Course in Functional Analysis, Conway" and as a corollary of the Riesz theorem (Example 5.9) he states what I have written in the title.
If I consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology and the measure $\mu$ that counts the points, I have a locally compact space so I can apply the Riesz Theorem obtaining $C_{0}(\mathbb{N})^*$ isometrically isomorphic to $M(\mathbb{N})$.
I agree that $C_{0}(\mathbb{N})^*=\ell^{1}$ but I can't see why $M(\mathbb{N})^*=  
\ell^{\infty}$.
I also don't understand the example 5.10 but I think that solving 5.9 would help me understand better 5.10.

Comment: Have you tried the map $\varphi:\ell^\infty\to (\ell^1)^*$ given by $\varphi(x)(y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$?

Comment: I don't want to prove it directly, I would like to use Riesz theorem. I also don't understand why you wrote $M(\mathbb{N})^*=\ell^{\infty}$